# Exclude one SKU from all price rules

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, sku, price-rules

I have one **SKU** I would like to **exclude** from all my **price rules**, so none of the price rules can be used on this specific SKU. But I have no idea how to do it. Can you please help?

Comment: Which Magento Version Are You Using ?

Comment: 1.9 something...

Answer (score 1):

First go to Product Attributes and select SKU attribute and enable option: "Use for Promo Rule Conditions" /this is for Magento 2, for Magento 1 should be the same or with the same meaning./, then save the attribute.
Go to Catalog Price rules, open your rule and go to Conditions section:
Click the green button,select from dropdown the SKU.
Make SKU is not and enter the sku of the product [image]

Comment: Hi. I'm sorry, but it's not working

Comment: I've tried everything and did the steps over and over again, but still not working

Comment: What do I put in "actions" I think this is where the problem occurs